# Questions about a small memory allocation program (41 lines)

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, alloc

*Questions*

1. Does the "memory storage array" allocbuf[10] save everything back to back. For example allocbuf[10] is full with {F, i, r, s, t, \0, S, e, c, \0] and I'll state how allocbuf became full. I imagine all of the information I save into allocbuf saves back to back.  So, as an example, after using **alloc(6)**, and assigning the returned character pointer to a variable **char *first**, the character pointer "first" points to allocbuf[0]. Now I assign, first = "First"; If I want to print "First", do I have to use a for loop, `for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) { 
   print allocbuf[i];
   }` to print out "First"?
2. If I assign first = alloc(1) and then assign first = "First", it will work, and overwrite the contents of allocbuf, correct?
3. Why does the line `printf("allocbuf: %s\n", allocbuf);` not print out the contents of allocbuf in my code?

I'm confident I'll be interested in more features of this program and I am excited to have your help.

I am excited to read any comments about this program, the functions, and memory allocation, although they may not answer on of the specific questions I have. So please share you knowledge and experience with me. Thanks :)

P.S. I haven't encountered malloc() in my book, K&R C Programming 2nd ed, yet, so, please, no comments saying use malloc().

*Code*

```
char *alloc(int); //return pointer to free storage in allocbuf[10]
void afree(int *); //free storage in allocbuf[10]
void strcpy2(char *, char *); //copy to, from
static char allocbuf[10];
static char* allocp = allocbuf;

main()
{
    char array4[5] = "4444";
    char* cp = "overwritten";
    char* copy = array4;
    char* occupyalloc;

    printf("cp: %s\n", cp); //"overwritten"
    printf("copy: %s\n", copy); //"4444"

    cp = "2"; //overwrite *cp = "overwritten" with *cp = "2"
    printf("cp: %s\n", cp); //"2"

    occupyalloc = alloc(4); //returns allocp 0, intended storage space is allocbuf[0] through allocbuf[3]

    cp = alloc(3); //returns allocp 4, intended use is allocbuf[4] through allocbuf[6]

    strcpy2(cp, copy); //copies "4444" into *cp, specifically allocbuf[4] through allocbuf[7]

    printf("cp: %s\n", cp); //"4444" , stored in allocbuf[4] through allocbuf[7] improperly
    printf("allocbuf: %s\n", allocbuf); //prints allocbuf -- not working
}

char *alloc(int n)
{
    if (allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n) 
    {
        allocp += n;
        return allocp - n;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

void afree(int *initial_storage_element_location)
{
    if (initial_storage_element_location >= allocbuf && initial_storage_element_location < allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE) 
        allocp = initial_storage_element_location;
}

void strcpy2(char *s, char *t)
{
    while (*s++ = *t++)
            ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should understand that if you have a line as `cp = "2"` then

- The compiler creates a **string literal** as `"2"`.
- This string literal is generally stored in the read only location of the memory.
- The address of the string literal is stored in the pointer `cp`

Now, if you are using dynamic memory allocation as

```
 char *first = alloc(6);
 first = "First";
```

What happens in the first statement is that a memory is allocated from the static buffer `allocbuf` and the address of the allocated memory is stored in `first`. With the second statement, you are overwriting the pointer `first` with a location in the read only memory. So you loose the previously allocated pointer and you have **memory leakage**

If you are using `alloc` you should copy the data `First` into the memory with `strcpy`

```
strcpy(first, "First")
```

> If I assign first = alloc(1) and then assign first = "First", it will work, and overwrite the contents of allocbuf, correct?

No, you not overwriting the contents of `allocbuf` but you are using a new pointer to read only memory.

> Why does the line printf("allocbuf: %s\n", allocbuf); not print out the contents of allocbuf in my code?

I will answer this in the context of the code posted.

```
occupyalloc = alloc(4); //returns allocp 0, intended storage space is allocbuf[0] through allocbuf[3]
cp = alloc(3); //returns allocp 4, intended use is allocbuf[4] through allocbuf[6]
strcpy2(cp, copy); //copies "4444" into *cp, specifically allocbuf[4] through allocbuf[7]
```

printf("cp: %s\n", cp); //"4444" , stored in allocbuf[4] through allocbuf[7] improperly
    printf("allocbuf: %s\n", allocbuf); //prints allocbuf -- not working

In this case, `allocbuf[0]` will be `\0`, as you are not modifying `occupyalloc` variable.

Note also that `"4444"` requires 5 bytes and you are only assigning 3 bytes.

Comment: I am really grateful for your effort. I have a question, for example, cp = alloc(3), then if I use strcpy(cp, "4444") it will store 4444\0 in allocbuf[0] through allocbuf[4], which may cause errors. Or no.

Comment: `cp = alloc(3)` by itself will not cause errors as you have already allocated 10 bytes in `allocbuf` But. if you later do another alloc `cp2 = alloc(5)` then the second alloc will overlap with the data stored and cause errors.